# How to acess folders from asset folder in android

Tags: android, file

I am working with ArcGIS sdk for android and it has a method called `RouteTask.createLocalRouteTask` Which takes the path of a folder as one of its argument.And That folder should contain 6 files inside of it.So how am I suppose to give the path of that folder which is inside my asset folder.
The folder name is arc and this is what my structure looks like[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the above answers are going to help u if u use the stream to copy your file from asset folder to the external storage by checking if it does not exist in ur external storage device.[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)

Answer (score 1):

You can give path of `assets` folder like this:

```
file:///android_asset/<folder_name>/<file_name>
```

In your case it, will be

```
file:///android_asset/arc/Navigation_ND_schema
```

Comment: I tried this File f1=new File("file:///android_asset/arc/Navigation_ND_schema");               and checked if f1 exists,but it doesn't  so does any one has another solution?

Answer (score 1):

> you can access folder inside the asset folder like this:

```
file:///android_asset/" + "folder Name/"+"fileName.extension"
```